# Memory issues with ResultSet and SQL Server 2012

Tags: java, sql-server-2012, resultset

I have some java code that is doing the following:

```
 Statement stmt = GetMsSqlConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                                                 ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID=1");
 //do stuff with recordset
 rs.close();
 stmt.close();
```

This is part of a loop where I'm going through different IDs on the table.  The problem is that while this is looping, I'm seeing my SQL Server process's RAM is growing on each iteration.  When I step through my code, I notice that the line causing the issue is on the executeQuery call.  I'm not surprised that this is causing some increased RAM use, but I would think that rs.close and stmt.close would free up the resources on my SQL Server.  Is there some better of handling this or something in my environment I need to look at to make sure that I'm freeing up all the resources before the next iteration?

Comment: The server is likely to defer cleanup until some threshold is reached.  Garbage collection is expensive so it isn't done every single time you release resources. If you run thousands of these does server memory grow without bound?  I'll bet it reaches some threshold and then drops.

Comment: This is a loop that can run for 100k+ times, in those cases the memory seems to hit a ceiling at around 2900 MB.  I'm working on a machine with 12 GB of RAM currently and my concern is mostly with program being able to run on computer with <4 GB of RAM.  Is the upper bounds proportionate to the amount of RAM available?

Comment: I know next to zero about MSSQL specifically, but every other database I've worked with has knobs (parameters) to set memory usage limits.

Comment: The server is simply caching mostly recently accessed pages.  MSSQL will use all the memory available in the system if allowed to.  It is not a memory leak, and MSSQL will not run out of memory, it will simply start evicting least used pages from its cache.

Comment: @Brettw You are correct. you should write that as a proper answer. not a comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is simply caching most recently accessed pages. MSSQL will use all the memory available in the system if allowed to. It is not a memory leak, and MSSQL will not run out of memory, it will simply start evicting least used pages from its cache.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing an out of memory issue while reading a resultset. A lot of current forums re-direct to using cursor and fetch size. However, When i added Cursor and fetch size options the OOM issue was not resolved. Instead, we observed that there is a deadlock while multiple threads try to read resultset and send the data across. 
Additionally, I did not notice any changes in memory consumption with changing fetch size and adding cursors :
Fetch Size  Cursor  MemoryConsumed(MB)
1           OFF     209
OFF         OFF     151
OFF         ON      132
OFF         OFF     160

While working on solving these issues, I happened to land on a blog which provides a better option for parsing read-only resultsets - ResponseBuffering=Adaptive option

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2007/05/02/what-is-adaptive-response-buffering-and-why-should-i-use-it.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb879937(v=sql.110).aspx

MSDN recommendation suggests DO NOT USE 'selectMethod'='cursor' for read-only large data-sets and a better option is to use 'responseBuffering'='adaptive'.

Using 'responseBuffering'='adaptive' we were able to get rid of both the problems:
1.  Out of Memory issue was resolved
2.  There were no deadlocks.
With the simplest code, data transfer of 2000000 records with 5 sources was failing. Adding adaptive response buffering enabled a transfer of 2000000 records per source with 40 sources without any issues. However, this does not mean that above 40 sources failed in transfer.

For large **read-only** result sets, setting response-buffering as adaptive is the best choice.

Here's a link to my detailed blog : 
http://pallavikaranjkar.blogspot.in/2014/10/context-existing-system-sends-data-from.html

Answer (score 0):

The server is likely to defer cleanup until some threshold is reached. Garbage collection is expensive so it isn't done every single time you release resources. If you run thousands of these in a row, a graph of server memory usage will likely display a sawtooth pattern where the memory increases linearly, then drops when GC occurs, repeating over and over.

All database servers have parameters to tune memory usage to the hardware they're running on.